# Facebook sharing preview image / description

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have been having an ongoing issue with a site I work on.  The site in question is:

http://guysboroughjournal.com/

The issue is that the main article image (and sometimes description) does not get automatically picked up by Facebook when sharing the website.  I have the following meta OG tags in the site:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="The Guysborough Journal" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.guysboroughjournal.com/_uploads/image/142957_2017-08-09.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<p><strong>AHOY:</strong> The Mist of Avalon made a big impression on sailors and landlubbers alike when it tied up at the Guysborough Marina on Wednesday, August 2. The two-masted schooner is part of the Tall Ships RDV 2017 event continuing throughout the Maritimes this summer.</p>
" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.guysboroughjournal.com/" />
```

But for whatever reason when anyone puts the site URL in to try to share on Facebook, the image from last weeks edition appears.  Sometimes the descriptive text from last weeks featured article also appears.  You can see that both the image and description tags are pointing to the correct image and showing the correct text.

I should not have to run the site through the Facebook debug tool manually everytime they update that main story.

What am I doing wrong???

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook caches the data. So yes you need to run it through Facebook debug tool if you are going to change it all the time. Or wait until Facebook refetches the information

Comment: So there is no way around this then??  Even though I am using the correct tags to point Facebook as to what image / text to use?

Comment: There is an API you can call to ask Facebook to clear it. But Facebook can not scrape your page every time someone shares something